# Consuming WCF service in Javascript/Jquery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted/published on the below path -

[newslettersubscriptiondev.mercola.com/NewsletterSubscriptionService.svc](http://newslettersubscriptiondev.mercola.com/NewsletterSubscriptionService.svc)

Want to call above `WCF service` in `Jquery Ajax Call`

**Code written in jQuery -**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cityClickJQuery() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://newslettersubscriptiondev.mercola.com/NewsletterSubscriptionService.svc/CheckEmailaddressValidateOnly",
            data: { EmaillAddress: 'pranav.bilurkar28@gmail.com', Source: 'ArticleBody' },
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                alert(jqXHR);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

In the above JS code `CheckEmailaddressValidateOnly` is the C# method defined in Service which requires 2 parameters.

**Design code -**

```
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClientClick="cityClickJQuery();" Text="click" />
        </div>
        </form> 
  </body>
```

Above JS code is not working.

Please Help.

Comment: Also: Is it really mean to be `emaillAddress` with two l's?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie How can i make public so that you could test it....

Comment: Is that service actually running at the moment? As you are using Visual studio you should be able to test the service using the WCF Test Client first

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The `emaillAddress ` which i passed as a parameter is used as a parameter in `[OperationContract]` of interface or should i use the actual parameter passed to the method? i am totally confused.

Comment: I was just pointing out that it was miss-spelt. So best to fix it everywhere :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The WCF is working properly...just wanted to confirm why Jquery Ajax call not working here.

Comment: Define "not working"? What error are you getting? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Please check attached screenshot above and let me know whether it should be `emaillAddress` or `EmailAddress` in `$Ajax data`

Comment: The two should match. Change all occurences of `Emaill` to `Email`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie But, is it necessary that both should match? And if not, which parameter we need to use as a data in $Ajax call.

Comment: If they do not match, the published interface may not match the receiving method. As I mentioned before, it is best to use the WCF Test Client utility and it will show you what it finds there (including whether the interface or implementation wins). If they don't match in the service, then by rights it should not even compile :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It compiles, i checked it now.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie `XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.` getting this error on I.E

Comment: Sounds like a cross-site scripting issue more than anything. You need to enabled CORS on that server. See: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I have added the code in Web.Config, but still shows same error - `required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).`

Answer (score 2):

First you should verify that you include attribute

```
[WebInvoke (ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Second you should use

```
data:JSON.stringify({EmaillAddress: 'pranav.bilurkar28@gmail.com', Source: 'ArticleBody'}),
```

The JSON.stringify is defined in http://www.json.org/js.html.

One more update After the successful return of data you will see that the data returned back should be accessed not with **data.d.EmailAddress**, but with **data.EmailAddress** instead. ASMX web-service place the data in the property d, but not WCF service.

Comment: Why is stringify required? the Ajax call will convert an anonymous object to a JSON string based on the dataType specified anyway.

Comment: @Shahid - Where i need to include `[WebInvoke (ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]`

Comment: @PranavBilurkar You have to place this before your method in WCF service for proper usage you can refer to this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386956/RestFul-WCF-JSON-Service-with-client-and-on-Mozill

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`data: { EmaillAddress: 'pranav.bilurkar28@gmail.com', Source: 'ArticleBody' },`
To

```
data: JSON.stringify({ EmaillAddress: 'pranav.bilurkar28@gmail.com', Source: 'ArticleBody' }),
```

Comment: This is not needed as the datatype is specified as JSON and conversion will occur automatically from an anonymous object.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie this would be the expected result, but unfortunately it doesn't ALWAYS work as intended.  I've run into a couple situations where I needed to explicitly call `JSON.stringify()`.  Most notably when the property name isn't surrounded by single quotes. I.E.`{ EmailAddress: 'blah' }` instead of `{ 'EmailAddress': 'blah' }`.  But it's pretty bipolar as to when it wants to be difficult, so it's just best to play it safe.